# Different java file for the same activity

Tags: android-activity, android-fragments

Is it better to make different class file for calculation in my unit conversion app or I should do all calculation in the same java file using function.
In terms of memory consumption and efficiency of the code.

Answer (score 1):

Having many small classes has no impact on performance.  There is a very slight memory overhead for making a new class rather than a function, on the order of 20 bytes for the class descriptor.  Function descriptors are 8 bytes if I remember correctly, but the difference is trivial unless you plan to make millions of classes for some reason.

Code clarity is far more important than worrying about a few extra bytes.